# ola-hallengren cleanup will not remove AOAG old DB backups if server fails over

Tags: ola-hallengren

ola-hallengren cleanup will not remove AOAG old DB backups if server fails over
anyone else experience this?

Comment: For issues with Ola's scripts, you may want to hit up his GitHub repo: https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution

Answer (score 0):

It will clean up only on active server or where the backup is taken from. You should put a custom job to do cleanup on the passive nodes.

This is what I have done in my environment :

- scan entire NFS for backups that are older than X-days and which have been backed up to tape (Archive bit is set).
- Use powershell to find and delete old backups - full, diff and tlogs. Note that scanning a large NFS for many files will take some time, so use robocopy with `/L` to fast list and then delete files.

Technically, Ola's backup solution should only care of the primary or the server that is taking the backups. Removing old files should be handled by a custom job.